# What's the best way to disentangle these questions about rising early, washing, and birkat hashachar?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, exact-duplicates

[When I wake up before Alot Hshachar and won't go back to sleep, what can/can't I do?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20710/when-i-wake-up-before-alot-hshachar-and-wont-go-back-to-sleep-what-can-cant-i) asks what is permitted when rising very very early -- washing, birkat hashachar, learning torah, eating, etc.

[Does one make Birkas Hatorah/Hashachar before alos hashachar?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10188/does-one-make-birkas-hatorah-hashachar-before-alos-hashachar) asks about birkat hatorah and birkat hashachar before the proper time, and also asks about washing.  It's not clear here if we're talking about getting up very early or getting up and then going back to sleep.  I think the former.

[If I wake up before dawn, do I wash my hands with a blessing?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7364/if-i-wake-up-before-dawn-do-i-wash-my-hands-with-a-blessing) also asks about washing and birkat hashachar, but adds the question about what changes if you're just getting up briefly versus staying up.

[Waking up in the middle of the night](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1173/waking-up-in-the-middle-of-the-night) asks about waking up briefly and washing.  It's not about birkat hashachar.

Also [Can I say the prayers of Birkot HaShachar and Tikkun Chatzot after Chatzot (Midnight), even if I don't sleep yet?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20723/can-i-say-the-prayers-of-birkot-hashachar-and-tikkun-chatzot-after-chatzot-midn) (thanks DoubleAA).

And [Torah learning any time of the day](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/21869/torah-learning-any-time-of-the-day).

These questions are all inter-connected but, as written, are not exact duplicates of each other.

What should be done about these questions?  Our tools include closing, merging, editing out parts of questions, editing in parts of questions, and generalizing existing questions.  (See comments for links to other relevant posts.)

Comment: We already have policy/discussions about multiple questions in one http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/335/759, about questions which end up with the same answer http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1339/759 http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/506/759 and about generalizing existing questions http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1299/759

Comment: Perhaps this is also sort of included http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20723/759